# Storing photo from camera in SQLite

Tags: android

I created a table in SQLite database for image, as well as class.
I am doing CRUD for this table and I've got stuck at getting Image. Does anyone know what to do next? The image is taken by camera.

```
public class Image
{
private int pid;
private byte[] photoByte;

public Image()
{

}
public Image(byte[] aPhoto)
{
    this.photoByte = aPhoto;
}

public void set_id(int pid)
{
    this.pid = pid;
}
public int getId()
{
    return pid;
}

public void setPhoto(byte[] aPhoto)
{
    this.photoByte = aPhoto;
}
public byte[] getPhoto()
{
    return photoByte;
}

}
```

Part of database:

```
        String CREATE_PHOTO_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + PRODUCT_PHOTO + " (" + KEY_PID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + KEY_PHOTO + " BLOB" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_PHOTO_TABLE);

public void savePhoto(byte[] image)
{

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_PHOTO, image);
    long newId = db.insert(PRODUCT_PHOTO, null, values);
}
public byte[] getPhoto()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(PRODUCT_PHOTO, new String[]{KEY_PID})
 ???????
}
```

Comment: `+ KEY_PHOTO + " BLOB" + ")";` Oh, my!! **Another database SBLOBBING app!** How many times more will I have to see this awful *anti-pattern*?! Please don't bloat your database with BLOBs. **Store the image paths**, instead!!

Comment: I do not know any other ways to do that.

Comment: Please re-read my comment above: `Store the image paths`.

Comment: @Joanna save the image to a file and save the file path in your database table

Comment: Ok thank you guys, I'll google and try that way :)

Comment: I guess there isn't even the need to google. You were ready to store a BLOB. Storing a path is just as easy as storing a string.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to store the image path instead. But if you have to store BLOB, then you need:

1. get bytes[] from cursor, as stated in this [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getBlob(int))

   `byte[] value = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(name));`
2. use byte[] in your need (write to file, bitmap, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Come on guys, Joanna wants to store pics on a Db, she's asking for help no to get scolded on her solution.

The solution is simple, You just need to return the Blob byte[]

```
public byte[] getPhoto()
{
    byte[] returnValue;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(PRODUCT_PHOTO, new String[]{KEY_PID});
    if(cursor.MoveFirst()) {
      returnValue = cursor.getBlob(0);
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return returnValue;
}
```

I do store images on Database, I store them in my android app and in my MySQL database (I send the byte[] to the MySQL database via a webservice) 
My android app image db is cleared daily, so is just like a temp storage, but on my MySQL Db I have a little more than 30k (and growing) records with images and I don't have any issues saving them or retrieving them from my web solution.